# Почему скрипт, запущенный через ярлык Linux не запускает программу?

Tags: linux, bash, desktop

У меня есть два файла. Первый - это sh скрипт со следующим содержанием:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Запускаем программу PRO100 под wine."
wine PRO100.exe
```

Данный файл валяется в папке с программой и если запустить его прямо оттуда, то он прекрасно выполняет последнюю строку, то есть, я получаю то что хочу. Однако, если вызвать его при помощи ярлыка pro100.desktop, расположенного в /usr/share/applications:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=PRO100
Keywords=Pro100;graphic;design;3D;
Exec=sh /home/tryum/PRO100/start.sh
Icon=/home/tryum/PRO100/pro100.ico
Terminal=true
Categories=Graphics;3DGraphics;
```

...то выполняется только echo, 2-я строка из sh скрипта.
Может, кто-нибудь подскажет, почему? И как сделать, чтобы скрипт в итоге все-таки запустил мою программу через wine?

Comment: только это не ssh скрипт, а sh.

Comment: точняк, ssh - это, вроде как протокол связи.

Comment: Path=/home/tryum/PRO100

Comment: О, а чё, прога для поклейки обоев и расстановки двиванов пашет под вайном? О_о

Comment: Работает в лучшем виде )

Answer (score 4):

Просто пропишите полный путь к своей программе. Где то так

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Запускаем программу PRO100 под wine."
wine /home/tryum/PRO100/PRO100.exe
```

и все должно работать. Просто когда Вы запускаете через ярлык, то текущий каталог совсем другой, не тот который Вы ожидаете. И там нет файла PRO100.exe

Comment: Спасибо большое, сработало! )

Comment: @Andreymadmentat отметьте ответ лучшим, наверное?

Answer (score 1):

добавьте `cd $(dirname "$0")` второй строкой.

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]